# convert days hrs mins secs strings to [h]:mm:ss in excel

Tags: excel, parsing, split, excel-formula, vba

How do I make a formula or vba that would automatically detect the *days, hrs, mins* and *secs* and convert it into the right `[h]:mm:ss` once I paste it into excel? I have some data need to process and they are in the following formats (string):

```
134 days 10 hrs 41 mins 23 secs
109 days 40 mins 37 secs
67 days 10 hrs 37 secs
33 days 3 hrs 7 mins 21 secs
21 days 14 hrs 7 mins 46 secs
15 days 7 hrs 19 mins
15 days 3 hrs 45 mins 59 secs
15 days 7 mins 35 secs
13 days 2 hrs 56 mins 57 secs
18 hrs 45 mins 33 secs
```

Comment: Look into parsing the string using Excel VBA string functions, a long list of which can be found [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-string-functions/).

Comment: When in doubt, just record yourself doing it manually and see how it's doing the formatting.

Comment: Edited code to remove possible (disturbing) line feeds in cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fast VBA approach using arrays**

Here you find a fast VBA method using arrays and a helper function to calculate the conversion of date units hrs,mins and secs.

**Caveat** The first example below assumes a fixed string structure containing *every* unit part. You'll have to modify the split logic for such cases where days, hours or minutes are omitted.

> **see Edit in case (2)** to see how that could be done.

**Case (1) Fixed structure days + hrs + mins + secs**

```
Option Explicit             ' declaration head of code module         

Sub s2date()
' declare your variables
  Dim myUnits() As Long     ' array, ~~> redim below
  ReDim myUnits(0 To 3)     ' redim to ZERO based 1-dim array
  Dim v                     ' variant, receives one-based 2-dim data field contents
  Dim s         As Variant  ' temporary split value
  Dim i         As Long     ' counter array items
  Dim ii        As Integer  ' counter tokens
  Dim n         As Long     ' counter last row number
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheetName") ' << change to sheet where you store your sheet names
' get last row number
  n = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
' create one based 2-dim datafield array from your sheetname list
' (assuming start in cell B2, ending in row n, omitting title row)
  v = ws.Range("B2:B" & n)
  ws.Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"
' convert values hold in array
  For i = 1 To n - 1     ' loop through array items from 1 to n minus 1 title row)
      s = v(i, 1)        ' get your date string, e.g. "134 days 10 hrs ..."
      s = Split(s, "s ") ' split it at last unit characters "s "
      For ii = LBound(s) To UBound(s)  ' parse each single token
          myUnits(ii) = Val(Trim(Split(s(ii) & " ", " ")(0))) '
      Next ii
    ' convert units to date via helper function
      v(i, 1) = calcDate(myUnits)
  Next i
' write back dates in datafield array v to column C:C
  ws.Range("C2:C" & n) = v
End Sub
```

**Helper function**

```
Function calcDate(ar) As Double
' Purpose: Helper function to convert date units (long) to date, called by s2date()
  Const days = 0:    Const hrs = 1:    Const mins = 2:    Const secs = 3
' return date -- assuming to omit days count
  calcDate = ar(hrs) / 24# + ar(mins) / (24# * 60) + ar(secs) / (24# * 60 * 60)
End Function
```

> **===== EDIT =======**

The adapted code example below allows to use or omit each of the listed parsing strings "days", "hrs", "mins" or "secs".

*Caveat:* Use "days" as plural even for 1 day only or think about a `Replace()`.

**Case (2) Flexible structure days | hrs | mins | secs (Edited)**

```
Option Explicit     ' declaration head of code module
' declare date/time constants
  Const days = 0:    Const hrs = 1:    Const mins = 2:    Const secs = 3

Sub parseDate()             ' << changed procedure name, cf. comment
' declare your variables
  Dim myUnits() As Long     ' array, ~~> redim below
  ReDim myUnits(0 To 3)     ' redim to ZERO based 1-dim array
  Dim v                     ' variant, receives one-based 2-dim data field contents
  Dim s, term, temp         ' << variant, temporary split values
  Dim i         As Long     ' counter of array items
  Dim ii        As Integer  ' counter of parsed tokens
  Dim n         As Long     ' counter last row number
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheetName") ' << change to sheet where you store your sheet names
' get last row number
  n = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
' create one based 2-dim datafield array from your sheetname list
' (assuming start in cell B2, ending in row n, omitting title row)
  v = ws.Range("B2:B" & n)
  ws.Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"
' convert values hold in array
  For i = 1 To n - 1     ' loop through array items from 1 to n minus 1 title row)

      s = v(i, 1)        ' get your date string, e.g. "134 days 10 hrs ..."
      s = Replace(s, vbLf, "") ' EDIT/cf.comment: remove possible line feeds
      s = Split(s & " 0 s 0 s ", "s ")                       ' split it at last unit characters "s "
      For ii = days To secs: myUnits(ii) = 0: Next ii        ' clear values
      For ii = days To secs  ' parse each single term
          term = Trim(Split(s(ii) & String(4, " "), " ")(1)) ' 2nd split delimiter is a blank character
          temp = Val(Trim(Split(s(ii) & String(4, " "), " ")(0)))
          If getTerm(ii) = term Then
             myUnits(ii) = temp
          Else
             If term = "hr" Then myUnits(hrs) = temp
             If term = "min" Then myUnits(mins) = temp
             If term = "sec" Then myUnits(secs) = temp
          End If
                    Debug.Print i + 1 & "/getTerm(" & ii & ") " & getTerm(ii) & " = " & term & " => " & _
                          "hrs=" & myUnits(1) & ", mins=" & myUnits(2) & ", secs=" & myUnits(3)
      Next ii
    ' convert units to date via helper function
      v(i, 1) = calcDate(myUnits)
  Next i
' write back dates in datafield array v to column C:C
  ws.Range("C2:C" & n) = v
End Sub
```

**Helper functions**

```
Function calcDate(ar) As Double
' Purpose: Helper function to convert date units (long) to date, called by s2date()
' return date -- assuming to omit days count
  calcDate = ar(hrs) / 24# + ar(mins) / (24# * 60) + ar(secs) / (24# * 60 * 60)
End Function

Function getTerm(n As Integer) As String
' Purpose: Helper function to get abbreviation string (without plural s)
  Dim abbrev:  abbrev = Array("day", "hr", "min", "sec")  ' << added abbreviation string
  If n > 3 Then Exit Function
  getTerm = abbrev(n)     ' nth term = e.g. "day"                              '
End Function
```

Comment: Added a flexible approach that should meet your requirements. Feel free to mark this as accepted if it's a helpful solution. BTW have  a look at 'How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)' (stackoverflow.com/help/mcve <https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve>), too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure what goes wrong but it seems to be not working. I created an VBA accordingly but nothing happen.

Comment: Do you get any error message (which code line)? -  Check: Did you Change your strings, do they end with "s"? Did you write constants (`Const`) to the declaration head? Did you Change the worksheet Name to yours? Code assumes data in column B:B and rewrites them to C - if there are no data in B, you won't get something.

Comment: Another try: Change `Sub s2date()` to e.g. `Sub parseDate()`; though it worked in my VBE (Visual Basic Editor), the procedure name might cause an issue.

Comment: I copy and paste your VBA into mine and the only thing that I change is the worksheet name. I were trying on a test worksheet where I copy and paste the strings into column B. Actually, the rewrites did appear in column C but it was just 0:00:00.

Comment: Second try: (1) As apparently there's no error message and column C gets filled with `0:00:00`, code is running but receives `0` values. (2) Units are only filled if all your date string units end with an *"s"* plus a blank character if there's a following term. - Therefore I assume you might have **line feeds** (`ALT+Enter`) in column C cells after *"s"* and terms aren't recognized in this case. => Go to the `For i = 1 To n - 1` loop, and write AFTER  `s = v(i, 1)`  one new code line: `s = Replace(s, vbLf, "")` removing such line feeds.

Comment: Runtime error appear. <pre>term = Trim(Split(s(ii) & String(4, " "), " ")(1)) ' 2nd split delimiter is a blank character<pre>

Comment: (1) Did you insert the second try? (2) Additionaly I suggest to insert the following code line before the above cited line: `Debug.Print "Item " & i, "s(" & ii & ")" = """" & s(ii) & """"`. Do you get any debug message in the immediate window of your VBA Editor (VBE) where the code stops? - Tell me at least the last ones.

Comment: The error message - Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range